# Как сделать выполнение функции при наведении на объект (JS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код
https://jsfiddle.net/25q0ex97/3/.
(отрабатывает только в новых версиях Chrome)

Он должен срабатывать при наведении

```
document.getElementById('page').onmouseover = function(){
document.getElementById('paste').click();
};
```

Код отлично срабатывает при загрузке локальной версии.
Но при загрузке "из вне" (видимо из-за работы iframe) для работы кода требуется "соприкоснуться" с окном - именно кликом.

Тоесть обычное наведение курсором на сам iframe не активирует код.

Но в тоже время, вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/richardcwc/qdjkreo5/ где код срабатывает в iframe, прямо алертом.

Читал за promise, может дело в этом, но со своей базой ничего там не нашел :(

Подскажите :(
Спасибо!

Comment: Консолька выдает Uncaught (in promise) undefined - Promise.then (async) - paste.onclick - document.getElementById.onmouseover.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/839712/33274  здесь не совсем то , и даже не нативный js, но функции одни и теже

Comment: `Onhover` событие вам поможет.

Comment: как его прикрутить? :(

Comment: @NewView, а есть такое событие?

Comment: Дело в том, что в приведенном примере код просто выполняется, не зависимо от действий пользователя, в то время как ты хочешь отлавливать именно действия пользователя, поэтому ты должен, как ты выразился _"соприкоснуться" с окном_

Comment: jquery [`.hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) например. В 'чистом' [javascript] `onmouseover`, но событие более известное как `hover` с учетом познаний в `css` основных вопрашующих :) вот код который должен помочь автору: `$("#ele").on("mouseenter", function() {...}).on('mouseleave', function() {...});`

Comment: Увы :( https://i.imgur.com/JjJ9nXP.jpg